# How do I rotate only shadow in text-shadow?

Tags: css

I'm trying to rotate my shadow only, but I rotate my object with it. How do I only rotate the shadow

```
    text-shadow: 20px 20px 1px red;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: You don't. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can not rotate the shadow on its own. You will need to apply the shadow to a different element (for example an absolute positioned pseudo element, that takes the same width & height as your element itself), and then rotate only that.

Comment: You probably try yo mirror your text, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061032/how-to-reflect-heder-text-like-mirror-on-the-bottom  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651639/reflecting-text-with-gradient-effect-in-css

Answer (score 1):

**You can't rotate `text-shadow` directly but you can use below method to get your expected result.**

Using this method now you can also apply other `CSS` to your text shadow text. For that you have to get same content text in `title` also.

```css
.text-rotate {
  position: relative;
  line-height: initial;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text-rotate:after {
  content: attr(title);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px red;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  
}
```

```html
<div title="Test Text" class="text-rotate">Test Text</div>
```